# send/receive a struct with TCP/IP socket on windows 7 64bit

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, struct

searching here for my problem, I've found more discussion about this, but seems that solution it's not simple for send a struct with a socket.

I don't understand how can send struct with socket in safe mode.

I need to use struct to send my information, and receive it correctly, without loosing any data.

So, the situation is this: the client have to send to server this struct:

```
typedef array<array<double,4>,4> Matrix4x4;

struct data
{
       bool shot;
       Matrix4x4 position;
};
```

where the Matrix4x4 are like this:

```
Matrix4x4 T1 = {{
        {{-1.0000,   0.0000,  -0.0000,   0.1531}},
        {{0.0000,   0.0000,  -1.0000,   0.1502 }},
        {{-0.0000,  -1.0000,  -0.0000,   1.0790}},
        {{0 ,       0,        0,   1.0000    }} }};
```

Every packet of data to send, have the matrix changed and the bool true or false; I need to receive it and can access to bool and matrix.

I'm using PraticalSocket class

http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/practical/

for send/receive on Windows 7 64bit, with visual C++ 2010 on a 64 bit project.

For sending struct, I'm doing this:

```
#include "PracticalSocket.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

#define servAddress "192.168.0.117"
const unsigned short SOCKET_SERVER_PORT = 27500;

typedef array<array<double,4>,4> Matrix4x4;

Matrix4x4 T1 = {{
    {{-1.0000,   0.0000,  -0.0000,   0.1531}},
    {{0.0000,   0.0000,  -1.0000,   0.1502 }},
    {{-0.0000,  -1.0000,  -0.0000,   1.0790}},
    {{0 ,       0,        0,   1.0000    }} }}; //example for testing send

//packet to send
struct data{
    bool shot;
    Matrix4x4 position;
};

struct data primo = {true, T1};

//socket TCP



int main()
{
try{
    TCPSocket sock(servAddress, SOCKET_SERVER_PORT);   
    sock.send(&primo, sizeof(struct data));
}catch(SocketException &e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

cout<<endl<<"Matrix and bool sendend server"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The "Send" to server goes OK (from this client, no error) but the server has error on receive. I notice that the recv() function need a char buffer...so, that error it's due to this...

Someone can give me an example of code, that help me to send and receive correctly this struct without loosing data from client to server?

The two PC's are the same architecture (windows 7 64bit, intel processor, same RAM and hardware..)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: maybe this will help ? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13071/Programming-Windows-TCP-Sockets-in-C-for-the-Begin

Comment: Don't use `structs` as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. By using a `struct` you are introducing half a dozen dependencies between the machines. Define an application protocol in octets and write yourself a library to send and receive it. Or use an existing protocol.

Comment: I've updated my question, if you can help me plese.

Comment: You've updated your question without reading the comments. Using `struct` as a network protocol is a bad idea. You introduce dependencies on the processor architecture, the processor mode, the compiler, the compiler version, the compiler options in effect when the `struct` was compiled, the surrounding #pragmas, ... Don't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems while sending data across network.

1. With the simpliest case assumption, when sender and receiver are build with the same compiler version and both run on the machines with the same (or very close) architecture (OS, CPU, 32/64 etc), You can use C structs "as is".
2. With the most complex case, when you do not know anothing about receiver (different OS, different programming language etc), You should use one of serialization methods: XML represendation for data layer, HTTP for protocol layer and TCP as transport.
3. Of course, you can use libraries, various RPC implementations etc.
   Assumed, you have p.1 (simpliest case), you should do the following:
4. Setup compliler to pack struct with 1-byte alignment.
5. Include guards in the struct: header, footer and length:
   struct data
   {
   char header; // set this to some very specific value, for example 0x02 
   int64 length; // put sizeof(data)
      bool shot;
      Matrix4x4 position;
   char footer; // set this to some very specific value, for example 0x03
   };
6. Develop receiving procedure to wait for header (transmission starts with 0x02), then receive length (its size is well defined sizeof(int64)), then read length bytes and check footer (transmission stops with 0x03)
7. Have a Good luck

Comment: I've update my question, now it's more clear...if you can Sergey, tell me how can I do that...

Answer (score 2):

A TCP connection *is* a byte stream. So start by documenting your protocol in terms of what bytes will be sent and received. Then implement code to send and receive precisely the bytes you specified. Then, you can troubleshoot by the following technique:

1. Does the sender send precisely the bytes the protocol specifies? If not, stop, the sender is broken.
2. Does the recipient correctly handle the bytes the protocol specifies? If not, stop, the receiver is broken.
3. The protocol is broken, since the sender and receive both follow it and the system as a whole still doesn't work. (This will happen a lot. It takes lots of experience to get protocols right.)

If you don't document the protocol at the byte level, troubleshooting will be nearly impossible. So, please, don't skip this step.

Comment: Thanks David...I'm beginner about socket...never doing one before this try...and so, I'm not a veteran about protocol...thanks for your ideas..